# How do I install mount.cifs on CentOS 5.5 64 bit?

Tags: centos, samba, mount

What package installs `mount.cifs`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`yum install samba-client`

For reference, I used the command `yum provides '*/mount.cifs'` to determine the package.